# Fetch data from mongo db in spring boot application where collection name & fields to fetch are known at runtime

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate, mongorepository

I need to create a spring boot batch job in which, I need to fetch data from mongoDB where I don't have info about collection name & fields to fetch at coding time. I get this info only when the batch starts.
E.g. When batch starts, I can read properties file where I get collection name by 1 property & another property gives list of fields to fetch, third filed provides criteria/condition for query
So, due to this, I cant have a Java POJO defined which have mapping for collection or I cant create any MongoRepository\Template (collection name is known at runtime).

What I want to know is, just like plain old native SQL, if i get to know fields name & table name, on the fly, SQL can be build & can be fired to get the data:

```
String dynamicQuery = "SELECT " + commaSeperatedFieldsList + " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + criteria;
```

Is there any way by which same thing can be achieved in spring boot + mongo DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MongoTemplate` for this which can be autowired as spring provides and configures it for you automatically.

It has a

```
find(Query query, Class<T> entityClass, String collectionName)
```

method which lets you define a custom collection name and a custom entityClass.

For the dynamic query use `BasicQuery` as `Query` impl to pass a raw mongo json query and fields/projection as json if you want to limit the fields returned.

Use `org.bson.Document` as entityClass which is basically a `Map` implementation which lets you iterate over the fields in a dynamic manner.

```
mongoTemplate.find(new BasicQuery("{ name: \"mongodb\"}", "{ name: 1}"), Document.class, "your-collection-name").forEach(x -> {
    x.get("name"); // access a specific field

    x.forEach((key, value) -> {
        // iterate over all fields
    });
});
```

When you deal with a large result consider using `MongoTemplate`'s `stream()` method in the same way as this doesn't load all documents into memory at once and you can process it during execution one by one.

Comment: Yes this works. I have made some changes as to use different mongo DB because I need to use 3 different mongo DBs in same application. Also, i'm not using bson; fetching the JSON from mongo & using it as is in business logic.Thanks.